# select array of class objects field

Tags: java, arrays, class, processing

I have an enum and a class with two fields:

```
enum types {
    nan,
    num,
    text,
    col,
    dress
  };
class GeneType {
  String name;
  types type;
  GeneType(String name, types type) {
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
  }
}
```

I have also array of objects that are using this class

```
final GeneType[][] geneNames = new GeneType[][]{
  {
    new GeneType("Unknown", types.nan),
    new GeneType("Age", types.num),
    new GeneType("Fav number", types.num),
    new GeneType("Height", types.num),
    new GeneType("Name", types.text)
  },
  {
    new GeneType("Unknown", types.nan),
    new GeneType("Not Sure", types.nan),
    new GeneType("This", types.nan),
    new GeneType("That", types.nan),
    new GeneType("The other", types.nan),
    new GeneType("Eye color", types.col),
    new GeneType("Fav color", types.col),
    new GeneType("Name", types.text)
  }
}
```

I wand to select array of names using the simplest method to set tab names (String[])

```
new Tabs(x, y, wid, hei, orientation, thingsToShow,
 geneNames[howMuchDataNeed(thingsToShow.size())].name)
```

thingsToShow is arrayList of otherClass

How to select array of **geneNames[index].name**?

Comment: You could make a method that returns the array based on the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `geneNames[index]` you will get one of the internal arrays based on the `index` value you have provided. For example, if `geneNames[0]` is called, you will get the following array as the result.

```
[
    new GeneType("Unknown", types.nan),
    new GeneType("Age", types.num),
    new GeneType("Fav number", types.num),
    new GeneType("Height", types.num),
    new GeneType("Name", types.text)
]
```

Then what you require is to **map** this array of `GeneType` objects to an array of their corresponding names. For that, you can use Java's `stream` APIs as follows.

```
String[] names = Arrays.stream(geneNames[index])
        .map(gene -> gene.name)
        .toArray(String[]::new);
```

---

**Update:** **Implementation without using Java `stream` APIs**

```
GeneType[] selected = geneNames[index];
String[] names = new String[selected.length];
for (int i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
    names[i] = selected[i].name;
}
```

Comment: this could be the answer that I want to implement, but unfortunately I thougth, that my android processing compiler will pass that code and it would, but the debuger catched two errors (associated with **->** and **::** characters

Comment: Then you may be using an older JDK version (<JDK8) which does not support these `stream` APIs. So I have updated the answer with an alternate implementation that does not use `stream` APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
int index = 1;
String[] names = Arrays.stream(geneNames[index])
    .map(gene -> gene.name)
    .toArray(String[]::new);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names));
```

output:

```
[Unknown, Not Sure, This, That, The other, Eye color, Fav color, Name]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using toString() overriding method in GeneType class.
I hope this code will help you.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

enum types {
    nan,
    num,
    text,
    col,
    dress
};

class GeneType {

    String name;
    types type;

    GeneType(String name, types type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
    
    
}

class question {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final GeneType[][] geneNames = new GeneType[][]{
            {
                new GeneType("Unknown", types.nan),
                new GeneType("Age", types.num),
                new GeneType("Fav number", types.num),
                new GeneType("Height", types.num),
                new GeneType("Name", types.text)
            },
            {
                new GeneType("Unknown", types.nan),
                new GeneType("Not Sure", types.nan),
                new GeneType("This", types.nan),
                new GeneType("That", types.nan),
                new GeneType("The other", types.nan),
                new GeneType("Eye color", types.col),
                new GeneType("Fav color", types.col),
                new GeneType("Name", types.text)
            }
        };
        ArrayList<GeneType> names = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < geneNames[0].length; i++) {
            names.add(geneNames[0][i]);
        }
        System.out.println(names);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't propably the best option, but it pass through.

```
String[] SelectNames(){
  GeneType[] carry = geneNames[index];
  String[] toReturn = new String[carry.length];
  for(int i=0; i<toReturn.length; i++)
    toReturn[i]=carry[i].name;
  return toReturn;
}
```